# To manage xcode workspace

Tags: xcode, workspace

I have few iphone applications which uses same classes. These applications run fine, but I face problem when I want to change something in apps, suppose I want to add one new feature to all of my applications. For this I need to do same changes in all the projects. So I want to create a master application, which will contain all common resources of applications in it. Each application will take the resources from master app and add more if it has something extra. Can I use workspace concept here? I don't know much about workspace or dependency management in workspace. Can anybody help me in this matter? Please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A workspace is just one or more projects grouped together. One way that people solve the kind of problem you describe is to create a framework or library project that holds all the code you want to share between the projects. Then you can include this framework or library in the projects that build your various apps. You may find it easier to put everything together in one workspace or you may not depending on how complex your apps are and your work style. The options would look like:

**Everything Together Workspace**

- Shared Library A Project
- Shared Framework B Project
- App C Project
- App D Project
- ...

  OR

**App C Workspace**

- Shared Library A Project
- Shared Framework B Project
- App C Project

**App D Workspace**

- Shared Library A Project
- Shared Framework B Project
- App D Project

The main disadvantage to putting everything together is that it can lead to quite a few projects, only a few of which you care about at any one time. In this case you select which particular app you want to build by selecting its project in the top left of the Xcode toolbar.

The main disadvantage to separating apps out into separate workspaces is that projects can only be opened in one workspace at a time. So if you want to make changes to App C and App D at the same time you will have errors if you open both workspaces at once since Shared Library A and Shared Framework B can only be open in one at once.

Splitting things out into logically related projects does gain you a lot of flexibility. On the other hand you pay the price in having to make top level configuration changes in each separate project. You can get around this using xcconfig files to store common configuration parameters for all your projects in one place. Rob Napier's describes how to do this in his blog on [Using Xcconfig](http://robnapier.net/build-system-1-build-panel).